# Dynamic sql for IN clause pl-sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a situation where i'm builduing an sql in a string and somewhere in the sql string i have this `WHERE`clause with `AND` :

```
ls_sql := ls_sql ||   
                    'and a.name IN( SELECT regexp_substr(''' || ls_activity_config || ''', ''' ||  lc_form || ''',' || 1 || ',' ||' level) FROM DUAL ';
```

Don't mind the `regexp_substr` method. My problem is that `ls_activity_config` is an array of string `('a','b','c')` and `a.name` column can have a value of `'a'` or `'a-#1`' or `'a-#2'` and so on. What I want to do is to match even these last values with '-#no' at the end.

What I've tried:

```
SUBSTR(a.name,1,INSTR(a.name,'-#',1) - 1);
```

This works when the a.name column has the value with `'-#no'` in it but won't work when the value doesn't contain it. That's normal because `INSTR` function will return 0. 
Any ideas on how to make this work for both values (with `'-#no'` or without it at the end)??

I was able to find a simpler solution

```
NVL(SUBSTR(a.name, 1, instr(a.name,' || '''-#''' || ',' || '1)-1), a.name)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `REGEXP_LIKE` maybe? I haven't focused too much on your task, but at a first glance, I think this might be useful in your case.

Comment: I think this could work as well, i'm thinking of the overhead difference between `REGEXP_LIKE` and `SUBSTR`, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    So to better illustrate your problem. Check below example.

    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN INSTR(A.NM,'-',1) > 0
        THEN SUBSTR(a.NM,1,INSTR(a.NM,'-',1) - 1)
        ELSE A.NM
      END no#
    FROM
      (SELECT 'a-#1' nm FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'a-#2' nm FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'a-#3' nm FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'a' nm FROM dual
      )A;


----------------Modified query for further requirements-------------------------

SELECT b.name
FROM homs.t_objects b,
  (SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN INSTR(A.NM,'-',1) > 0
      THEN SUBSTR(a.NM,1,INSTR(a.NM,'-',1) - 1)
      ELSE A.NM
    END no#
  FROM
    (SELECT 'a-#1' nm FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a-#2' nm FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b-#3' nm FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a' nm FROM dual
    )A
  )
WHERE b.name LIKE '%'||a.NO#||'%';
```

Comment: Can I have after this some `IN` statement so the values returned from your query be compared with the ones from the `IN` clause??

Comment: Because basically your query(if possible plus the `IN` statement) is going to be just another filter in the `WHERE` clause of a bigger `SELECT` statement

Comment: Yupps values can be used easily in IN Clause

Comment: So you need to put the values of this query into another query? Is that so?

Comment: So this should work :`SELECT b.name from homs.t_objects b WHERE 
(SELECT CASE WHEN a.name like '%-#1%' then substr(a.name, 1, instr(a.name,  '-', 1)-1)
else a.name end from homs.t_objects a  IN( SELECT regexp_substr('a,b,c' , 1 , level)
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(  'a,b,c'  ,  '[^,]+'  ,  1 ,  level) IS NOT NULL))`

Comment: Basically u want to use the result of the query like a,b,c and select some data from homs.t_objects table?

Comment: Yes exactly but a,b,c are without '-#1' or so and a.name can or cannot have the '-#1' at the end

Comment: So I need to match the values from `IN` in some way similar to `LIKE` the values from a.home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96990/discussion-between-avrajit-roy-and-andrei-maieras).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample query:

```
select case when a.name like '%-%' then substr(a.name, 1, instr(a.name, '-', 1)-1)
else a.name end from table_name;
```

We are searching if the string contains '-' in it. If there is '-' query returns string before '-' else it will return actual string it self.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will try to integrate this, maybe one problem will be that my sql is dinamically created but should work, thank you

Comment: Is this sintax valid: `SELECT * FROM table where (select case when .name like '%-%' then substr(a.name, 1, instr(a.name, '-', 1)-1)
else a.name end from table_name) IN ('a','b','c')`

Comment: I mean will the `select` with `case` which returns a list of values from a table be compared with the values from the `IN` clause?

Comment: I mean will the `select` with `case` which returns a list of values from a table be compared with the values from the `IN` clause? cause i'm getting a `missing expression` error

Comment: Syntax is incorrect. Here is the right one: SELECT * FROM table where (select case when a.name like '%-%' then substr(a.name, 1, instr(a.name, '-', 1)-1) else a.name end from table_name a) IN ('a','b','c')

Answer (score 1):

Am I over-simplifying this or don't you just want a `REGEXP_REPLACE()` call around a.name that keeps only the first part of a.name up to but not including the optional "`-#<digit>`"?  The various examples below illustrate this.  All that instr/substr stuff gives me a headache (granted regular expressions can give their share of headaches too, heh).

```
SQL> with a(name) as (
     select 'a'      from dual union
     select 'a-#3'   from dual union
     select 'b'      from dual union
     select 'c'      from dual union
     select 'efs'    from dual union
     select 'efs-#4' from dual
   )
   select regexp_replace(name, '^(.*)?(-#\d)', '\1') "a.name"
   from a;

a.name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
a
a
b
c
efs
efs

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

EDIT: I realized after adding some more test data that REGEXP_REPLACE returns the original string if the match criteria is not found, which could return unexpected results.  So, I reworked things to include a where clause that ensures a.name only has the expected values (a single lowercase letter followed by the end of the line or an optional dash) in the first place before testing against the array of values.  So, make sure a.name is in the format you expect before using it in your test.  Anyway this goes to show once again, "always expect the unexpected" and test for it!

```
SQL> with a(name) as (
        select 'a;'     from dual union
        select 'a-#3'   from dual union
        select 'a'      from dual union
        select 'b'      from dual union
        select 'c'      from dual union
        select 'efs'    from dual union
        select 'efs-#4' from dual
      )
      select regexp_substr(name, '^([a-z])($|?-)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "a.name"
      from a
      where regexp_like(name, '^[a-z]($|?-)');

a.name
------
a
a
b
c

SQL>
```

Comment: CAVEAT - The `REGEXP_REPLACE` call returns the original string if a match is not found to the pattern.  This could result in unexpected results returned.  I will edit my answer to show an alternative.  You need to make sure a.name meets the criteria before comparing it to your array.

Comment: In your second example I think `efs` should also appear in the results, first example looks like to return the desired results, anyway what I've done and seems to work is adding `NVL(SUBSTR(a.name, 1, instr(a.name,' || '''-''' || ',' || '1)-1), a.name)` in the left part of the `IN` statement, thank you

Comment: @Andrei Maieras - Not according to your specs, which only list a single letter. That's why I included an example with > 1 letter, to show it would not be included.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I changed a little my question so the combination of letters would be '-#' because I can have as `a.name` something like `'abc - def'` and this should not be truncated, only 'abc-#no' and maybe a more specific and accurate search wodul be a regexp so the format to be `letters + '-#' + digit`, but for now with `NVL` I think it's ok, thanks again